# Как убрать кнопку после нажатия на нее в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

[image: Кусок кода с функцией клавиатуры]

Как убрать кнопку из функции клавиатуры после ее нажатия? Обыскал весь интернет ничего не нашел.

Comment: Почему просто не создать новую клавиатуру без существующей кнопки?

Comment: Эта клавиатура должна создаваться сама, можете подсказать, как это реализовать

Comment: Ваш бот ведь в цикле работает, правильно? В начале каждой итерации создавать новую клаву из букв, которые хранятся в листе ВНЕ цикла. Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку просто делаете list.remove(кнопка) и в следующей итерации уже будет клавиатура без нее

Comment: То есть мне нужно создать список, в котором будут буквы, затем внести его в функцию клавиатуры и вызвать его после сообщения?

Comment: Создайте для начала цикл бота, а потом внесите поправки в вопрос

Comment: Как объявить список в клавиатуру?